# post thumbnail not showing up with shortcode

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I have created a shortcode with this code:

```
add_shortcode('recent-newsletter', 'recent_newsletter');
function recent_newsletter() {
    $recentnews = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'newsletter',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ));
    $news ='';
    if ($recentnews->have_posts()) {
        while($recentnews->have_posts()){
            $recentnews->the_post();
         if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
             $news .= get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
            }
         $news .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
        }
    } else { $news = 'no posts';}
    wp_reset_postdata();
return $news;
}
```

First off the CPT is working fine and images show on the main query.

The problem I'm having is that I want to pull the thumbnail size, not the full image.

this line:

```
         $news .= get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
```

displays no image.  If I change it to this:

```
         $news .= get_the_post_thumbnail();
```

The full image shows up.  How do I display just the thumbnail sized-image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument of [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) is not the image size that you want to use. It's the ID or object of the post whose thumbnail you want to get. To get the thumbnail size, set the *second* argument to `'thumbnail'`. The first argument can just be set to `null` to get it for the current post:

```
$news .= get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: that's makes sense.  I wasn't sure about calling the id when in a loop

Answer (score 2):

You should pass first argument as post id in `get_the_post_thumbnail()`. As you're getting thumbnail if look you can pass the id of post like

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' );
```

you can also specify the size of the image your want to show as

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), array( 100, 100) );
```